# Can't update Stripe coupons

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm working on food application project in which I need to implement stripe's payment and coupons. I'm trying to update the coupon values but can't update.

```
const update_coupon = async (req, res) => {
    const { percent_off, duration } = req.body;
    const couponId = req.params.coupon_id;

    try {
        // Retrieve the existing coupon
        const existingCoupon = await stripe.coupons.retrieve(couponId);
        // Update the specific fields
        existingCoupon.percent_off = percent_off;
        existingCoupon.duration = duration;

        // Save the updated coupon
        const updatedCoupon = await stripe.coupons.update(
            couponId,
            {
                percent_off: percent_off,
                duration: duration
            }
        );
        console.log("Coupon updated:", updatedCoupon);
        res.status(200).json(updatedCoupon); // Send a response if the update is successful
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error updating coupon:", error.message);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to update coupon" }); // Handle error
    }
};
```

> error : Received unknown parameters: duration, percent_off

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/coupons/update says, _"Updates the metadata of a coupon. **Other coupon details (currency, duration, amount_off) are, by design, not editable.**"_ - so I doubt this will be any different, when you are using the JS SDK ...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your use-case would be for doing this, but you can't update these attributes for a Coupon.

The only solution you would have would be to delete your existing Coupon (let's say it has an ID of `123456`), then create a new coupon with the new params and `id:'123456'`:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/coupons/create#create_coupon-id

Few notes about this:

- This will not change the discounts applied to existing objects that redeemed the old `123456` Coupon.
  For example, an old Subscription running with Coupon `123456` would carry on with the old Coupon params, unless you re-apply the Coupon in an update after the change.
- This would make things very difficult to troubleshoot if anything went wrong.